# Compiling java program with external libraries from command line

Tags: java, json, visual-studio-code, cmd, org.json

I am having difficulty compiling my java program from the command line. The program uses external libraries and I have had no issues compiling the program. However, upon running the program, the following error is generated:

```
C:\Users\...\App> javac -d bin -cp lib/json.jar src/*.java

C:\Users\...\App> java src/App.java
src\App.java:3: error: package org.json does not exist
import org.json.*;
^
src\App.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            ^
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: class App
src\App.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                                 ^
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: class App
3 errors
error: compilation failed

C:\Users\...\App>
```

The file structure looks like this:

[image]

How can I compile my program with its external libraries from the command line?

**UPDATE**

I've rearranged the file structure as advised and is now

[image]

However, I am still getting errors when compiling the program

```
C:\Users\...\App\src>javac -d ..\bin -cp lib\json.jar App.java

C:\Users\...\App\src>java -cp ..\bin:.\lib\json.jar App.java
App.java:3: error: package org.json does not exist
import org.json.*;
^
App.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            ^
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: class App
App.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                                 ^
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: class App
3 errors
error: compilation failed
```

Comment: If you are attempting to run the java app from inside the src folder, then you need to also place the external libraries or lib folder in the src directory (Not in a folder on an upper lever of the file structure). This `-cp lib/json.jar` is going to look for files inside the src folder only, for example, the absolute path would look like: `....../APP/src/lib/json.jar` which of course does not exist in the src folder.

Comment: If you want to retain your file structure use `../` to move up a level like so: `-cp ../lib/json.jar`

Comment: I'm attempting to run the file from the App folder which contains src and lib. The program compiles without errors but running 'java src/App.java' from the App folder generates the errors. How can I resolve that?

Comment: You need to edit your post to include the error, otherwise, we can only guess. You can't run `'java src/App.java` because that will look into the src folder. Make sure that the App.java file is directly in the APP folder, then from the APP folder run this command `java App.java` now what happens? If you get an error then edit your post to include ti, and show your updated file structure.

Comment: I've updated the post with the error for your reference. It says compilation failed at the bottom but when we compile with javac there are no output errors? Do you know what might be causing this to happen?

Comment: Was this but a mistake `-cp ..\bin:.\lib\json.jar` it shouldn't need bin, or to move up a folder level? With the updated file structure you should no longer need to move up a directory, so your original command should work `java -cp lib\json.jar App.java`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `java xxx.java`, it's `java SomeNameoOfTheClassFileName`.

You can just click the add button on the right of `Referenced Libraries` under the `Java Projects` panel:

[image]

Then you can import the `org.json.*` successfully. Then you can click the `Run Java` button on the top-right of the VSCode, the Java extension will help you compile the java code automatically.

Or you just want to compile the java file manually, you can read [this article](https://www.codejava.net/java-core/tools/how-to-compile-package-and-run-a-java-program-using-command-line-tools-javac-jar-and-java).

Depending on the first picture's structure it will be like this:

First

```
javac -cp lib\json.jar -d classes src\App.java
```

After that, create a manifest.txt next to README.md and contains:

```
Main-Class: App  //if your App.java has package src, it will be src.App
Class-Path: lib\json.jar
//need keep a blank line here
```

Then

```
jar cfm App.jar manifest.txt -C classes .
```

Last

```
java -jar App.jar
```